# curl commandline to php

Tags: php, linux, curl

I have a command i've been having a problem converting to php.

curl -i -X POST -u user:userpass --url http://cloud.netelignet.ca/virtual_machines/:virtual_machine_id/startup.xml

Comment: Just curious what you've tried? Do you have some code to post?

Comment: what's the `:virtual_machine_id` in the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it equates to the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://cloud.netelignet.ca/virtual_machines/:virtual_machine_id/startup.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$username = 'user'; $password = 'userpass';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: That looks close to what i had except missing two of the options but it still doesnt work. Maybe i'll try to contact them.

Comment: "Does not work" is not useful.  Are you getting an error?  Have you sniffed the request?

Comment: I must have done something wrong. It was not getting any output at all from echo, var_dump, print_r but I did get it working with the following code.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://cloud.netelignet.ca/virtual_machines/:virtual_machine_id/startup.xml");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);